# Create a calculated measure to get last week Numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a measure to get last week's numbers in the current week's row. I have a date column and CTR(Core Resources Online). In the image below we have a calculated measure M, which shows the Sum of resources in each week. Column M3 is also a calculated Measure where I was trying to get last week's number in the current week's value.

What exactly I'm trying to achieve is if my current week is incomplete, as it is now, I want the row of 30th July to show last week's number, which is 292. But whatever I try I get a blank value there.

My calculated Measure is this :

```
IF(WEEKNUM(Max(Vw_DailyMaxCTRByTeam[AvgHour])) = WEEKNUM(Today()),
SUM(Vw_DailyMaxCTRByTeam[MaxAVGCTR]),Vw_DailyMaxCTRByTeam[Weekno]=WEEKNUM(TODAY())-1),
[M])
```

Here I'm checking first if week number of my latest date is equal to today's week number, then calculate the sum of last week otherwise let it remain as it is. With this measure, I get a blank against the current week.

[image]